# Version of Fodor's Lemma

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

I know that pressing down functions exist, but it is not intuitively clear to me. Is there a way to prove the existence of such functions in this form:
$$f: \omega_1 \to \omega_1 $$ $$\exists \alpha \in \omega_1. f^{\to}(\alpha) \subseteq \alpha$$ (image of $\alpha$)

Also, would that be useful to prove this tricky version of pressing down lemma:

If  $f: \omega_1 \to \omega_1$ and $f(\alpha) < \alpha$ then $\exists \beta \in \omega_1. |f^{\gets}\{\beta\}=\omega_1|$
(pre-image of $\beta$)

Is there a straightforward way of showing $\exists \beta \in \omega_1. |f^{\gets}\{\beta\}=\omega_1|$ without using clubs?

Comment: What is $f^{\to}$? Do you mean $f^{-1}$?

Comment: I'm not sure you've stated what you want to ask correctly...as stated, the existence of such $f$ is very trivial.  (For instance, if $f$ is the identity than any $\alpha$ works.  Or fix $\alpha$, and let $f$ be any function such that $f(\beta)\geq \alpha$ for all $\beta$.)

Comment: @EricWofseyn but then $\alpha$ is not in the image of $f$. Isn't it?

Comment: How is the "image" of a singleton can have any cardinality larger than $1$???

Comment: @AsafKaragila it is not a singleton, it can be any ordinal

Comment: Where did you find that notation of $f^{\to}$ and $f^{\leftarrow}$? I have never seen that before.

Answer (score 3):

The existence of such $f$ is trivial: take the identity function, then $f^{-1}(\alpha)=\alpha$, for any $\alpha$.

So this is indeed not useful for proving that any regressive function has a large fiber. But note that Fodor's lemma states more than just cardinality. It tells you that there is a "large fiber", where large here means stationary.

To prove Fodor's lemma, you need to essentially remember the definition of a diagonal intersection, and the theorem that the diagonal intersection of $\omega_1$ clubs (in $\omega_1$) is a club again. Using this the proof more or less writes itself: suppose $f$ is a regressive function which is a counterexample, choose clubs witnessing this, take the diagonal intersection, it is non-empty, and show that any $\alpha$ in that non-empty set implies a contradiction.

(Morally speaking, this is the right proof as well, since without the axiom of choice Fodor's lemma holds for $\omega_1$ if and only if the diagonal intersection of any family of $\omega_1$ sets which contain a club also contains a club.)

---

Here is an argument showing that the cardinality of a fiber has to be $\omega_1$, it does not appeal directly to Fodor's lemma, although it hides the use of clubs.

Suppose that every fiber is countable, then for every $\alpha<\omega_1$, there is some $\beta$ such that if $\gamma>\beta$, then $f(\gamma)>\alpha$.

Pick some $\alpha_0$, and let $\alpha_{n+1}$ be the least ordinal such that $f(\beta)>\alpha_n$ for all $\beta>\alpha_{n+1}$. Now consider $\alpha=\sup\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}$. Then by the fact $f$ is regressive, $f(\alpha)<\alpha$. On the other hand, if $f(\alpha)<\alpha$, then there is some $n$ such that $f(\alpha)<\alpha_n$. This is now a contradiction, since $\alpha>\alpha_{n+1}$, so $f(\alpha)>\alpha_n$.

Comment: But can we show $\exists \beta \in \omega_1. |f^{-1}\{\beta\}=\omega_1|$ without the diagonal intersection?

Comment: Well, yes and no. It is consistent without the axiom of choice that $\omega_1$ has countable cofinality. In which case it is possible to contradict this. So some choice has to enter. Moreover, if there is a regressive function with countable fibers, with $\omega_1$ regular, then there is a canonical choice for a club disjoint from each fiber, in which case we can do the diagonal intersection argument without any choice. So, morally speaking (again), any argument is essentially through the diagonal intersection argument. I'm not sure why you are trying to hard to avoid it.